# validator to return Promise or Observable : Custom async validator : Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom async validator for my registration form where it checks if an email is a valid email or not using third party API. this is ref link of the API website -

https://www.zerobounce.net/email-validation-api.html

I am trying to implement it using RxJs debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged. In the form control I have two more validations required and pattern. But I am always getting this error - **Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.**

I have searched several examples but nothing worked. Thank you in advance.

**Validator -**

```
export class UniqueEmailValidator{
   static createValidator(_ajaxService : AjaxService){
        return (control : AbstractControl) =>{
            const apiKey = environment.emailValidatationKey;
            const baseUrl = 'https://api.zerobounce.net/v2/validate?';
            if(control.valid){
                return control
                .valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    debounceTime(800),
                    distinctUntilChanged(),
                    switchMap((email : string) => _ajaxService.apiCall('', `${baseUrl}api_key=${apiKey}&email=${email}&ip_address=''`, 'GET', true)),
                    map(res => res.json()),
                    map((validationStatus : any) => {
                        if (
                            validationStatus.status == "valid" &&
                            validationStatus.mx_found == "true"
                        ) {
                            return null
                        } else {
                            return { isEmailInvalid : true }
                        }
                    })
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Register Component -**

```
this.registration = this._formBuilder.group({
  firstName: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-z A-Z]+$')
  ]),
  lastName: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-z A-Z]+$')
  ]),
  email: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}')
  ],UniqueEmailValidator.createValidator(this._ajaxService))
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895576/angular-async-validator-is-not-called-with-switchmap/65914854?noredirect=1#comment116632247_65914854

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I have ended up with, which resolves my problem -

**Validator -**

```
export class UniqueEmailValidator {
    static createValidator(_ajaxService: AjaxService) {
        let validatorSubject$ = new Subject();
        let debouncedSubject$ = new Subject<string>();

        debouncedSubject$
        .pipe(debounceTime(500), distinctUntilChanged())
        .subscribe((email: string) => {
            const apiKey = environment.emailValidatationKey;
            const baseUrl = 'https://api.zerobounce.net/v2/validate?';
            _ajaxService.apiCall('', `${baseUrl}api_key=${apiKey}&email=${email}&ip_address=''`, 'GET', true).subscribe({
                next: (validationData : IEmailValidation) => {
                    if (
                        validationData.status == "valid" &&
                        validationData.mx_found == "true" &&
                        (
                          validationData.sub_status == "alias_address" ||
                          validationData.sub_status == ""
                        )
                    ) {
                        return null
                    } else {
                        return { isEmailInvalid : true }
                    }
                },
                error: (validationFailed) => {
                    console.log(
                        "Failed to validate the Email Address",
                        validationFailed
                    );
                },
            });
        });

        return (
            control: AbstractControl
        ):
        | Promise<ValidationErrors | null>
        | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            debouncedSubject$.next(control.value);
            let promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
              validatorSubject$.subscribe((result) => resolve(result));
            });
            return promise;
        };
    }
}
```

**Component TS -**

```
this.registration = this._formBuilder.group({
  firstName: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-z A-Z]+$')
  ]),
  lastName: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('^[a-z A-Z]+$')
  ]),
  email: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-z]{2,3}')
  ],UniqueEmailValidator.createValidator(this._ajaxService))
})
```

**Component HTML -**

```
<div *ngIf="formcontrol.email.errors.isEmailInvalid">
   <p>Use a working E-mail address.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you piping validators Observable from `valueChanges` Observable? That doesn't make much sense since the validator runs on valueChange and when it's dirty. And you are also returning the desired Observable **only if the control is valid**. So when sync validators mark the control as Invalid this one won't return the Observable. I guess that's what's causing the error.

Try this approach:

```
export class UniqueEmailValidator {
  static createValidator(_ajaxService: AjaxService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      const apiKey = environment.emailValidatationKey;
      const baseUrl = 'https://api.zerobounce.net/v2/validate?';

      return timer(800).pipe(
        concatMap((email: string) =>
          _ajaxService.apiCall('', `${baseUrl}api_key=${apiKey}&email=${email}&ip_address=''`, 'GET', true)
        ),
        map(res => res.json()),
        map((validationStatus: any) => {
          if (validationStatus.status == 'valid' && validationStatus.mx_found == 'true') {
            return null;
          } else {
            return { isEmailInvalid: true };
          }
        })
      );
    };
  }
}}
```

I'm using similar approach to this one in a project where I have to check export path on the filesystem. One thing I'm not so sure about is distinctUntilChanged. Isn't that filtered already