# Angular async validator is not called with switchMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to check that username typed by user is unique. Thus, I'm sending an HTTP request for every `input` event from the target element. And, of course, I need to debounce this operation, so as to get 1 HTTP request for X `input` events following each other within a specific interval.

The problem is - as soon as I add `switchMap` the code stops working and `switchMap` callback is never called.

The working code without a `switchMap`:

```
public static createUniqueFieldValidator(
  target: 'username' | 'email' | 'phone',
  checker: (value: string) => boolean,
  userService: UserService
): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<NullableType<ValidationErrors>> => {
    if (!!control.value && checker(control.value)) {
      return fromPromise<SomeReturnedType>(
        userService.checkUnique({ [ target ]: control.value })
      ).pipe<NullableType<ValidationErrors>>(.......);
    }

    return of<null>(null);
  };
}
```

If I add a `switchMap` its callback is never called

```
public static createUniqueFieldValidator(
  target: 'username' | 'email' | 'phone',
  checker: (value: string) => boolean,
  userService: UserService
): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<NullableType<ValidationErrors>> => {
    if (!!control.value && checker(control.value)) {
      // We do get here, I've checked
      return timer(300).pipe<NullableType<ValidationErrors>>(
        switchMap<number, Observable<NullableType<ValidationErrors>>>(
          (): Observable<NullableType<ValidationErrors>> => {
            console.log('SwitchMap');// The whole callback is never called
            // Here I'm supposed to make an HTTP request instead of returning a null
            return of<null>(null);
          }
        )
      );
    }

    return of<null>(null);
  };
}
```

If I replace `timer` with

```
of<string>(control.value).pipe<NullableType<ValidationErrors>>(delay(), switchMap.......)
```

it doesn't work either.

If I replace `switchMap` with `switchMapOf` it works but without a debounce time.

Comment: Do you want `timer` or `debounceTime`? NOTE: Rememeber that if your inputs has another sync Validator and not pass, the asyncValidator is not executed

Comment: What I need is if, for example, user types "qwerty", app should send 1 request to the API instead of 1 request for each char. Sync validators are passed, but I tried to remove them completely, nothing changed. About timer / debounceTime - look at the end of the topic, the `of` / `delay` option seems more reasonable to me but doesn't work either. It looks like Observable is stopped being subscribed to once you add a `switchMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723416/showing-error-after-form-submit-in-angular-reactive-form/56728046#56728046)

Well, you can create your validator like:

```
checkIfNotRegister(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> |
                                       Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      return timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(_=>this.service.getWebName(control.value).pipe(
        map(res => res ? { repeat: "name yet register" } : null)
      )))

    };
  }
```

But you see in [this forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-post-submit-validation-and-error-handling-7z3ukp?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts) that the message "Validating.." is showed each change of the input -if you change the timer by 10000ms, this effect is more observable-

Comment: This seems exactly like my code above. For which I never get to the callback (`_ => this.service.....`).

Comment: in the forked stackblitz looks like work (If you open the console, you see that the service only show the "last" input :(

Comment: Yes, I checked that. That's the topic of the discussion - why at least 2 working solutions don't give the expected result in my case and where I should start looking to find the problem.