# Angular Reactive Forms - custom validator calling service

Tags: angular, validation, angular13

Angular application and reactive forms.
I have a requirement to validate the uniqueness of the name of every new record created.
I have back-end endpoint doing this and returning boolean value as a result.
Now I need to hook it up to the form field but I cannot find the way of doing it.
Ideally I need a custom validator I could add to the field validators but any solution will fit actually.

Here is the form:

```
groupForm : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        shortName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.pattern(this.shortNameRegex)]),
        fullName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(100)]),
        emailDomains: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        addressLine1: new FormControl(null, []),
        addressLine2: new FormControl(null, []),
        townCity: new FormControl(null, []),
        county: new FormControl(null, []),
        eircode: new FormControl(null, [Validators.pattern(this.eircodeRegex)]),
        ratingScales: new FormControl(null, []),
    });
```

and here is the function call:

```
checkGroupUnique() {
    this.onLenderGroupService.checkGroupUnique(this.groupForm.controls.shortName.value).subscribe(res => {
            this.isGroupUnique = res;
        });
    }
```

however I do not call it anywhere yet, I need to add such validator to first field named "shortName".

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn

Comment: Joulukuusi - I read that but thing is I have no clue how to use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723416/showing-error-after-form-submit-in-angular-reactive-form/56728046#56728046 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895576/angular-async-validator-is-not-called-with-switchmap/65914854#65914854

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create asynchronous validators in Angular:

```js
groupForm = new FormGroup({
  shortName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, ..., this.checkGroupUnique.bind(this)]),

...

checkGroupUnique(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
  return this.onLenderGroupService.checkGroupUnique(control.value).pipe(
    map(isUnique => {
      if (isUnique) {
        return null; // no error
      } else {
        return { isGroupUnique: true };
      }
    })
  );
}
```

```html
<label *ngIf="groupForm.controls.shortName.errors?.isGroupUnique">
  Group name is not unique!
</label>
```

Comment: when I try this I got incompatibility issue that check function is not ValidatorFN compatible or so

Comment: Could you show the actual error message so that we could debug it?

Comment: error looks like this:     TS2322: Type 'Observable<ValidationErrors | null>' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Type 'Observable<ValidationErrors | null>' provides no match for the signature '(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null'.

28         shortName: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.checkGroupUnique(),

Comment: You're invoking the function instead of just passing it. The correct syntax does not include brackets: `[Validators.required, this.checkGroupUnique]` (so not `this.checkGroupUnique()` but `this.checkGroupUnique`)

Comment: still no luck, that's what I got now: ERROR TypeError: this is undefined    checkGroupUnique

Comment: Oh, then `[Validators.required, this.checkGroupUnique.bind(this)]` would do the trick

Comment: it appears that such validator is quite a die hard, I have solved this with onChaqnge($even) on that field and relevant flag. However this solution also works but worse :) thumb up anyway